# How to Fix No MBean found for Worklight project?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-runtime

I have a problem when deploying my Worklight project on the server . It shows the following Error Message :

```
FWLSE3041E: No MBean found for Worklight project 'MyProject'. Possibly the Worklight runtime web application for Worklight project 'MyProject' is not running. If it is running, use JConsole to inspect the available MBeans.
```

and when I tried to preview my application it showed this message :

```
SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.verifyServletInitialized:420'
```

Comment: What is your Worklight version?

Comment: 6.2.0 but the project was created with the version 6.1

Comment: Can you provide server logs?

Comment: I Edited the Question and added the server's logs

Comment: After importing the 6.1 project into Worklight Studio 6.2, did you re-build the application? Can you describe the steps you've done?

Comment: Run As--> 4 - Build Settings and Deploy Target  , then Run As --> Run on Worklight Development Server

Comment: I Solved The problem by creating a new Worklight Project and coping my files and it works just fine :) , Thank You idan for your help and time

Comment: Please write it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved The problem by creating a new Worklight Project and copied all my files , it works just fine :) I used Worklight 6.1 instead of 6.2

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using Worklight 6.2 CLI, but recreating the project did not work.

One issue that I had was that  worklight did not build a .war-file properly, so I copied the .war-file from a backup.

Edit: This happens regularly in our project now, and we have no idea why. We fix it by invoking any procedure, which makes it work until you restart the server. Worklight must be building something when invoking a procedure that it does not do when building.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the war file.   I end up needing to  Run As --> Run on Worklight Development Server to reinstall the war file; before my ant script that builds the apps/adapters can deploy.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by fixing a recently created security test in

```
server/conf/authenticationConfig.xml
```

The problem was I mispelled the Realm name I previously defined.

Comment: I faced the same problem, and I found out that the authenticationConfig.xml file was causing the problem : in the loginModule there wasn't 'expirationInSeconds' attribute in the version 7.0 but when migrating to 7.1, It adds automatically this attribute with the value "-1". You should change its value to an integer value like by default "3600". This will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by deleting the application from the worklight server and rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

Delete WorklightServerConfig folder in workspace and rebuild your application.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this in MobileFirst 7.0 (Fka Worklight) by opening the Servers view, Window -> Show View -> Servers. Then expanding the MobileFirst Development Server and right click on the project in question, chose delete.

Once you do that go back to the applications' directory in the "apps" directory and right click -> Run As -> Run On MobileFirst Development Server

This should rebuild and deploy the project on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using ibm jdk not open jdk. My solution is to make sure the env parameters are correct

- export JAVA_HOME = $your_ibm_jdk
- export PATH + $your_ibm_jdk/bin:$PATH

run `java -version` to make sure the setting work