# No MBean found for worklight project

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-studio

I am trying Worklight 6.2 on this version of eclipse:

Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Build id: 20140612-0600

The eclipse is clean, clean workspace and just installed Worklight 6.2 - 6.2.0.00-20140719-1643.

When I build my project for deployment to the development server I get error:

```
Failed to deploy application 'MyApp' to Worklight Server: No MBean found for Worklight project 'SiriusProject'. Possibly the Worklight 
runtime web application for Worklight project 'SiriusProject' is not running. If it is running, use JConsole to inspect the available 
MBeans.
```

If i try to deploy my adapter I get this error:

```
Adapter deployment failed: No MBean found for Worklight project 'MyProject'. Possibly the Worklight runtime web application for Worklight 
project 'MyProject' is not running. If it is running, use JConsole to inspect the available MBeans.
```

Early in the console output I see

```
A preview contributor threw an exception while updating the URL
NullPointerException. check logs.
```

But I dont know which logs it is asking me to check.

Comment: You could try Window -> Show View -> Other -> Error Log for the Eclipse log, and also, for the server log, you should look at: <your_workspace_path>/WorklightServerConfig/servers/worklight/logs

Answer (score 2):

See if any of these suggestions help: [How to Fix No MBean found for Worklight project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551480/how-to-fix-no-mbean-found-for-worklight-project)

Ex:

- Run As--> 4 - Build Settings and Deploy Target , then Run As --> Run on Worklight Development Server
- Create a new Worklight project and copy files

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to use eclipse Kepler instead of Luna.

Answer (score 1):

Delete WorklightServerConfig folder in workspace and rebuild your application.

Another option is to Switch your workspace.