# MaximoAnywhere 7.5.2 Build failed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, maximo-anywhere

Enviroment Detail

Server :Websphere 8.5.5.3
Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2

when executing build all-dist

BUILD FAILED

> E:\ibm\Anywhere5\MaximoAnywhere\build.xml:97: The following error occurred while
>    executing this line:
>   E:\ibm\Anywhere5\MaximoAnywhere\anywhere-apps-builder.xml:875: The following err
>   or occurred while executing this line:
>   E:\ibm\Anywhere5\MaximoAnywhere\anywhere-apps-builder.xml:871: Failed building a
>   pplication: FWLST2020E: Application is from platform version 7.1.0 and ant versi
>   on is 6.3.0. Upgrade your ant-builder to app's platform version and retry.

when I am trying to execute build all-deploy  command but faild on maximo Anywhere I am getting the following error

```
-deploy-adapter:
    [wladm] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    [wladm] <config userName="wasadmin" productVersion="6.3.0.00-20150404-1503"/>
    [wladm] Error accessing http://192.168.1.44:9081/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/worklight/adapters?locale=en_US: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    [wladm] FWLSE3002E: The resource is not found.
    [wladm] FWLSE3041E: No MBean found for MobileFirst project 'worklight'. Possibly the MobileFirst runtime web application for MobileFirst project 'worklight' is not ru
it is running, use JConsole to inspect the available MBeans. If it is not running, full error details are available in the Worklight Development Server Eclipse Console vi
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a great many questions about this issue. Why not search first? See here for example: [How to Fix No MBean found for Worklight project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551480/how-to-fix-no-mbean-found-for-worklight-project)

1. > I solved this by fixing a recently created security test in
   >
   > server/conf/authenticationConfig.xml
   >
   > The problem was I mispelled the Realm name I previously defined.
2. > Delete WorklightServerConfig folder in workspace and rebuild your application.
3. > I was able to fix this in MobileFirst 7.0 (Fka Worklight) by opening the Servers view, Window -> Show View -> Servers. Then expanding the MobileFirst Development Server and right click on the project in question, chose delete.
   >
   > Once you do that go back to the applications' directory in the "apps" directory and right click -> Run As -> Run On MobileFirst Development Server
   >
   > This should rebuild and deploy the project on the server.
4. > I Solved The problem by creating a new Worklight Project and copied all my file

And so on.